# vtiger how to enable the error reporting?

Tags: php, vtiger

I installed vtiger, but i am having some problem with it, i asked the help desk team they told me to enable the error reporting

how can i do that please?

Comment: Can you please tell which version of Vtiger you using?

Answer (score 1):

In file config.inc.php comment the first line:

```
version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & E_ERROR) : error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED  & E_ERROR & ~E_STRICT); // PRODUCTION
```

in other words add //, this is the result:

```
//version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & E_ERROR) : error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED  & E_ERROR & ~E_STRICT); // PRODUCTION
```

And uncomment the line (or add it if there no exist)

```
ini_set('display_errors','on'); version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);   // DEBUGGING
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your environment (which you did not specify in your question).

You can set the error reporting directive with an appropriate reporting level in the php.ini of your SAPI:

```
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and enable error display:

```
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors = On
```

This might require reloading your server configuration afterwards.

You can set this [directive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at runtime:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

The server logs might give you some insight, too.

Answer (score 0):

**Non-techie no editing of configuration files answer:**

Go to the [vTigress.com blog](https://vtigress.wordpress.com/) and search for vtDebug. Find and download the zip and then install it with the Module manager (Cogwheel > CRM Settings > Studio > Module Manager).

Once installed there is a green circle with a white running man in it on the right hand side of the screen (underneath the cogwheel).

If you click on that, you can then switch on or off various debugging options.

Note that you will still need to be able to access the folders where these log files are stored so you can actually read them.

*If you can't get the vtDebug installed or working, remove the module and try the next bit:*

**More techie but still general answer:**

If you can log onto your vTiger install with a SSH client or have access to the install location via FTP, look for a file called "config.inc.php". Make a copy of that file. In the file there is a line you can uncomment to enable PHP logging.

Starts with

```
//version_compare
```

Remove the //.

That will switch on PHP errors so you can see them rather than the blank screen of doom.

In the same folder there should be another file called "config.performance.php". Make a copy of that before changing anything. In that file you will see something like:

```
'LOG4PHP_DEBUG' => false,
```

If you change that to

```
'LOG4PHP_DEBUG' => true,
```

That will turn on the logging and you should be able to see files created in the folder 'logs'.

(Sorry for the vagueness of this reply, but without version info or what type of system its installed on its hard to give an answer other than using generalities that should work on all installs).

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/DebugTechniques#PHP
(Also turn on php error reporting - you can find how to do it by searching)

Answer (score 0):

i got fustrated with the installation process of vtiger I ended up cheating after 2 days of unsuccessful installation /frustration I edited index.php and threw in this code on a hosted server, .htaccess did not help me at all

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
 ini_set('log_errors', 'off');
 error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting` will be overwritten in `config.inc.php`

edit config.inc.php

```
// Adjust error_reporting favourable to deployment.
version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') ....
//ini_set('display_errors','on'); versio ....
```

comment the first line, it's for production

uncomment the second line, it's for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Go to .vtigerfolder/modules/Install/views/index.php and change the code as shown in solution

```
protected function applyInstallFriendlyEnv() {
        version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : 
               error_reporting(E_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
            set_time_limit(0); 
    }
```

====Solution:======
The code below shows if your php version is less than 5.5.0 then set error reporting to notice, error and deprecated other wise or else set error reporting to E_error,E_notice,E_deprecated and E_strict which is changing the actual setting you set in php.ini

```
  //Change below line
version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : error_reporting(E_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);


    //USE This code instead
version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : error_reporting(~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & E_WARNING);
```